# How to join a discord server with a selfbot python

Tags: python, discord, request, discord.py, bots

I was trying to join a server with a selfbot using this code which seems not to be working:

```
import requests
#base url
url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{}"

headers = [{"Authorization":"token"}]
for header in headers:
    r = requests.post(url.format("invite code"), headers=header, json={})
    print(r.status_code) #prints 200 if all went well
```

I keep getting status code 400 and I don't know the reason.

Comment: Self-bots are against Discord's Terms of Service.

Comment: @Raymus I understand that it could be against discord's tos but I will be using it on my own risk so if you know how my problem could be solved please help me because I really need it